# UWP media player next track

Tags: c#, uwp

I am using a Media Element to play audio in a UWP project and have enabled TransportControls with Previous and Next buttons which don't work by default (nothing happens when pressed).
How do I get a "Click" event on these buttons? I don't know how to tell the buttons to actually play the "Next" or "Previous" track.

Comment: Does the following answer work?

Answer (score 1):

> How do I get a "Click" event on these buttons?

For your requirement, you could listen `SystemMediaTransportControls` `ButtonPressed` event, then you could get **Next** or **Previous** pressed. For more please refer [**Handle system media transport controls button presses**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/system-media-transport-controls#handle-system-media-transport-controls-button-presses) document.

```
private async void MyMedia_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{  
    var control = MyMedia.MediaPlayer.SystemMediaTransportControls;
    control.ButtonPressed += Control_ButtonPressed;
}

async void Control_ButtonPressed(SystemMediaTransportControls sender,
    SystemMediaTransportControlsButtonPressedEventArgs args)
{
    switch (args.Button)
    {
        case SystemMediaTransportControlsButton.Play:
            await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
            {
                mediaElement.Play();
            });
            break;
        case SystemMediaTransportControlsButton.Pause:
            await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
            {
                mediaElement.Pause();
            });
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Please note the next and previous button only works when playing `MediaPlaybackList`. Because, it is internal event and it only fires after the actual `MediaPlaybackItem` is played. UWP does not provide straight button click event. If only want listen button click event. you could custom `MediaTransportControls`. Please refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/custom-transport-controls).

```
public sealed class CustomMediaTransportControls : MediaTransportControls
{
    public CustomMediaTransportControls()
    {
        this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(CustomMediaTransportControls);
    }

    protected override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        Button PreviousTrackButton = GetTemplateChild("PreviousTrackButton") as Button;
        PreviousTrackButton.Click += PreviousTrackButton_Click;


        base.OnApplyTemplate();
    }

    private void PreviousTrackButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

}
```