# How to know when the user presses one of the MediaPlayerElement buttons (play, pause, next track, etc.)?

Tags: c#, uwp, mediaplayerelement

I have a UWP Desktop application for playing audios. I'm using a MediaPlayerElement and setting the MediaPlayer's Source property to a MediaPlaybackList. I have two questions:

1. How to know when the user presses one of the MediaPlayerElement buttons (play, pause, next track, etc.)?
2. How to change the running track programmatically?

   ```
            <MediaPlayerElement x:Name="mediaPlayerElement" 
                                AutoPlay="False" 
                                HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                Margin="0,0,0,100"
                                AreTransportControlsEnabled="True" >
                                <MediaPlayerElement.TransportControls>
                                    <MediaTransportControls 
                                             IsSkipBackwardEnabled="False"
                                             IsSkipBackwardButtonVisible="False"
                                             IsSkipForwardEnabled="False"
                                             IsSkipForwardButtonVisible="False"
                                             IsFastForwardButtonVisible="True"
                                             IsFastForwardEnabled="True"
                                             IsFastRewindButtonVisible="True"
                                             IsFastRewindEnabled="True" 
                                            IsFullWindowButtonVisible="False"
                                            IsNextTrackButtonVisible="True"
                                            IsPreviousTrackButtonVisible="True"
                                            IsZoomButtonVisible="False"/>
                                </MediaPlayerElement.TransportControls>
                            </MediaPlayerElement>

    MediaPlaybackList mediaPlaybackList = new MediaPlaybackList();

    public PlayerPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        CreatePlaylist();

        mediaPlayerElement.MediaPlayer.Source = mediaPlaybackList;
    }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

> How to know when the user presses one of the MediaPlayerElement buttons (play, pause, next track, etc.)?

Please refer to the case reply [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54900264/7254781). And listen `SystemMediaTransportControls` `ButtonPressed` event, then you could get Next or Previous pressed.

```
mediaPlayerElement.MediaPlayer.SystemMediaTransportControls.ButtonPressed += SystemMediaTransportControls_ButtonPressed;

private void SystemMediaTransportControls_ButtonPressed(SystemMediaTransportControls sender, SystemMediaTransportControlsButtonPressedEventArgs args)
{
    switch (args.Button)
    {
        case SystemMediaTransportControlsButton.Play:
            break;
        case SystemMediaTransportControlsButton.Pause:
            break;
        case SystemMediaTransportControlsButton.Stop:
            break;
        case SystemMediaTransportControlsButton.Record:
            break;
        case SystemMediaTransportControlsButton.FastForward:
            break;
        case SystemMediaTransportControlsButton.Rewind:
            break;
        case SystemMediaTransportControlsButton.Next:
            break;
        case SystemMediaTransportControlsButton.Previous:
            break;
        case SystemMediaTransportControlsButton.ChannelUp:
            break;
        case SystemMediaTransportControlsButton.ChannelDown:
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

> How to change the running track programmatically

What's the running track, do you means playing order? MediaPlaybackList has  [ShuffleEnabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.playback.mediaplaybacklist.shuffleenabled?view=winrt-20348)  property. You could set it as true to playing shuffle.

Comment: It is the track that is currently playing. For example, mediaplayerelement is playing track 3 of mediaplaybacklist and I need to switch to track 8 programmatically.